# On the hypothesis of the Additive Cousin Problem

Tags: homology-cohomology, several-complex-variables

The Additive Cousin Problem is the following:

> Assume that $D$ is a region (open, connected) of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Assume that the Dolbeault Cohomology Group of $D$, $H^1_{\bar{\partial}}(D)$ is equal to zero, and that we have an open covering of $D$ given by $\{ U_j:j\in J\}$. Suppose that we have  meromorphic functions $m_j\in\mathcal{M}(U_j)$ for every $j$ such that, whenever $U_i\cap U_j\neq \emptyset$, $$m_j-m_i\in\mathcal{O}(U_i\cap U_j).$$ Given this, we ask if there is $m\in\mathcal{M}(D)$ such that, in $U_j$, we have $$ m-m_j\in\mathcal{O}(U_j).$$
>   Finding such $m$ is called the Additive Cousin Problem.

Can the existence of the $m_j$ meromorphic functions be a consequence of the hypothesis $H^1_{\bar{\partial}}(D)=0$ ? Range's book seems to be implying this, but I do not know how this can be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem really assumes you have meromorphic functions satisfying certain conditions (perhaps with certain poles). You could always take all the $m_j$ to be constant and then there's no hypotheses at all needed for them to exist.

Perhaps you already understand how this goes, but if $H^{0,1}_{\bar\partial}(D)=0$, then by the Dolbeault isomorphism we have $H^1(D,\mathcal O) = 0$. Thus, the $\check{\rm C}$ech $1$-cocycle $f_{ij} = m_i-m_j\in Z^1(\scr U,\mathcal O)$ is a coboundary, so we have holomorphic functions $f_i\in \mathcal O(U_i)$ with $f_i-f_j=m_i-m_j$ on $U_i\cap U_j$. Therefore, the functions $f_i-m_i$ glue to give a global meromorphic function $m$.

Comment: Is there any loss in generality when it is assumed that the $m_j$ are all constant?

By the way, I couldn't understand very much of your second paragraph, but I hope to be able to do so soon.

Comment: Think about one complex variable. You want to construct a meromorphic function with prescribed principal parts at a discrete set of poles. You can do so locally, on disks, say, that overlap at none of the given poles. Then, knowing that $H^{0,1}(\Bbb C) = 0$, you know you can "glue" them together as I described to make a global meromorphic function with those prescribed principal parts.

Comment: It's quite clear now. Thanks for your help and you time, professor :)